# Use an image as label in Nvd3.js

Tags: nvd3.js

I would like to draw a discreteBarChart with Nvd3 using images in place of text label. Is it possible ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, but you can put images directly using d3 wherever you want, like for example:

```
d3.select("#chart1 svg").append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "img/20.png")
        .attr("width", 70)
        .attr("height", 105)
        .attr("x", 160)
        .attr("y",100);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a part of the API, but you can hack it in.

For example, to replace your x-labels with an image, do something like the following:

```
d3.selectAll('#yourChartId svg .nv-x.nv-axis.nvd3-svg g g g.tick')
  .select('text')
  .remove();

d3.selectAll('#yourChartId svg .nv-x.nv-axis.nvd3-svg g g g.tick')
  .append('svg:image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'images/myimage.png')
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 40);
```